# How do you make an ASP.Net 5 Application be able to consume class libraries?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Step 1: Open VS 2015 RC and create a new "ASP.Net Web Application"
[image]
[image]
Step 2: Right-click the solution, add a new windows "Class Library" (a normal one, not the "Class Library (Package)"
[image]

Step 3: Put a method in Class1.cs in the class library. Doesn't matter what.

Step 4: Right-click "References" in the Web Project and add a reference to your class library.
[image]

Step 5: From a code file in the web project, call the method you made in Class1.cs

So for me, Class1.cs looks like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void X()
    {

    }
}
```

And I added code in the web application like this:

```
        var x = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
        x.X();
```

Step 6: Try to compile, you will get this error:

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What magic must be done to make normal class libraries (of which I have a lot) work with ASP.Net 5 apps?

Comment: I can't reproduce this -- following your instructions it builds just fine. It would surprise me too if something as basic as this wouldn't work. I uploaded  the test project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qir4ul6uv8uv587/WebApplication2.zip?dl=0) which you can download and see if it works for you. It might help you pinpoint the problem area.

Comment: Hey awesome, thanks for trying. My ASP.Net 5 web application looks completely different from yours! Yours doesn't seem to have any of the supporting files. I'll edit my description above on how exactly I create the project. But in the meantime, here is a link to my sample project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10121209/AspNet5Test.zip

Comment: Here you go, I added some screen shots.

Comment: I noticed that I accidentally creating the project using .NET 2 template. After using .NET 4.5 I see the same situation as you; I suspect it has something to do with that class library type being incompatible with DNX and you'll have to use the newer version.

Comment: All the docs everywhere say that ASP.Net 5 will work with .net framework stuff: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/choosing-the-right-dotnet.html

Comment: The other class library (which works) is also .NET -- it's just targetted throughout the DNX. Or something like that. I'm not too familiar with the intricacies either but I recall reading that these new packages are required. I see this [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/references-and-class-library-asp-net-vnext-%E2%80%93-alpha-3) too: "*Note: We can’t use the normal “Class Library” template, it will not work because it doesn’t uses the new Asp.Net vNext project structure.*"

Comment: Interestingly, the first comment on that post is asking exactly what I asked here. Unfortunately, it never got an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When downloading your project and building, I got the following error in the output:

```
C:\REDACTED\AspNet5Test\src\AspNet5Test\Startup.cs(26,25,26,38): DNX Core 5.0 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Note, especially the `DNX Core 5.0` portion - .Net 4.5 libraries (such as your ClassLibrary1) are not compatible with .Net Core.

The easiest solution is to remove the dependency on dnxcore50 from your project.json file.

Current:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
        }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

Change to:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
            "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That was definitely the answer (which seems to be documented nowhere). Hopefully when the full version comes out the templates will be modified so that the VS2k15 ones work with existing class libraries out of the box, and the ones created by the command line tools work with the new .Net Core stuff.

Comment: I'd rather a checkbox list for framework versions just like selecting MVC and WebApi in old versions - I'm using Visual Studio to develop cross platform solutions!

Comment: Agreed. Choosing during project creation is ideal.

Comment: Just to add a note for everyone coming and looking at this answer in the future: this does not actually work with every traditional Class Library. In fact, it only works very rarely.

Comment: Do you have a new issue? It's been working for me since beta3.

Comment: From the above example, to the class library, add a reference to HtmlAgilityPack using NuGet. Make a method that uses HtmlAgilityPack (could just be a single line of code "var doc = new HtmlDocument();"). Now try to call that method from the ASP.Net 5 app. At runtime, I get a FileNotFound exception for HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I'm guessing that was after you've added the reference to ClassLibrary1 (Step 4). Unfortunately, it doesn't update the "wrapped" project.json with your added references; you can run `dnu wrap` from the command line to update them, I believe. Alternately, you can remove and re-add your reference (redo Step 4) upon any reference changes or just propagate the references like we used to do pre-VS2015.

Comment: That did not work. I ran it on the ClassLibrary1.csproj. The wrap\ClassLibrary1\project.json file definitely contains a reference to HtmlAgilityPack. But I still get the FileNotFound error. Do I need to run dnu wrap on the HtmlAgilityPack DLL in the packages folder?